# Removing lines on legend with geom_polygon in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to plot a map using geom_polygon ggplot2. When I add the "borders" on the map, it somehow also adds the "lines" on the legend too. Can anyone suggest ways to remove those lines on the legend (but at the same time keep the "borders on the map")

my codes as follow

```
ggplot(outputData, aes(long,lat, group = group)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(fill = meanadjsmr), colour = "black") + 
labs(x=" ", y=" ") + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = cust_brewer) + 
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

Comment: Try adding this to your ggplot call: `guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test without data, but try this:

```
#  Not tested...
ggplot(outputData, aes(long,lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = meanadjsmr)) + 
  geom_path() +
  labs(x=" ", y=" ") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = cust_brewer) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

You're getting lines on the legend because of `color=black`. You can get the borders using `geom_path(...)` instead.